# When a same performance script is re executed using performance testing tool then why response time change by noticeable amount ?

Tags: jmeter, performance

Like in first run time was around 20 secs and after re execution response time value slashed to around 2 secs

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information: what type of application are you testing? Does the application need to be "warmed up"? Have there been any changes pushed between runs? Do you have a dedicated network connection? All these factors can influence the outcome of a performance test depending on your configuration.

Comment: I agree the question lacks detail, but a good answer could provide insight into what a performance test can teach you about the flawed mental models people have about how software systems work.

Answer (score 1):

General thoughts:

Instability in performance tests can be caused both by the system environment or environment where the test tool is run.

If the usage of the system is stable, probably you would have to checkout the execution environment.

Beside that, you could have found a outlier. You should consider doing a more precise [statistical analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924371.aspx), creating a [normal distribution curve](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html), e.g.